# Astro - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I am moving my blog to Astro and wanted to import some javascript using jquery.

In the Layout file I first import the jquery file (3.6.1) and then import my javascript file.

```
---
import "../scripts/jquery.js";
import "../scripts/main.js";
---

<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

However I get the error (regarding the jquery file):

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing your files with `script` tag :

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yesterday I had tried it too but it didn't work; now it does (I think it is related to restarting the debugger).
However, to make it really work I had to merge the two js into one file because otherwise it couldn't find jQuery.
I think this is related to how Astro works.